# When would it be better to use `ActionCable::Channel::Streams#stream_from` over `#stream_for`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, publish-subscribe, conventions, actioncable

## Question

Is there a use case where `stream_from` has an advantage over `stream_for`?

### Example

In this contrived example, I create a `ChatChannel` which can connect to a different `room`s. Each version of the code also includes the method for broadcasting a message to that room and a comment in the `subscribed` method showing the room name should `room == '123'`.

#### Using `stream_from`

```rb
  class ChatChannel <  ApplicationCable::Channel
    def subscribed
      stream_from "chat_#{params[:room]}" #=> "chat_123"
    end
  end

  ActionCable.server.broadcast("chat_#{room}", data)
```

#### Using `stream_for`

```rb
  class ChatChannel <  ApplicationCable::Channel
    def subscribed
      stream_for params[:room] #=> "chat:123"
    end
  end

  ChatChannel.broadcast_to(room, data)
```

One interesting thing to point out is that using the `stream_for` approach, you can still use `ActionCable.server.broadcast("chat:#{room}", data)` (note the change of `_` to `:`) but you cannot use `ChatChannel.broadcast_to` with the `stream_from` approach.

### Reasoning

`stream_from` is more "dangerous" as it sets a global room which requires a convention maintained by the author(s). Additionally, broadcasting can only be done directly from `ActionCable.server`.

`stream_for` namespaces the room and broadcasting can be accessed from the channel's class method `broadcast_to`. While a global room is still created, the naming convention is maintained by Rails.

### Best Guess

The only difference that I've found so far is that `stream_from` would allow multiple channels to transmit the same message with a single call. E.g. If I had both a `ChatChannel` and `NotificationChannel` and both contain `stream_from 'common'`, I'd be able to broadcast on both channels at once with `ActionCable.server.broadcast('common', data)`. This seems like a code smell to me though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick correction on your example with the `stream_for` approach. `stream_for` requires a model so your example should be

```rb
 class ChatChannel <  ApplicationCable::Channel
    def subscribed
      room = Room.find params[:room]

      stream_for room 
    end
  end
```

Note:

Your approach will still work, the only difference is the resulting named broadcasting for the stream. This will make more sense as you will soon see.

Are there any differences between `stream_for` and `stream_from`? I'll say not much but to answer that question factually, let us look at how they both work under the hood.

### [`stream_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/Channel/Streams.html#method-i-stream_for)

Takes a model and inturn calls `stream_from`. The result is a serializable string that is used as the named broadcasting. So when you call stream_from on a

1. model, the named broadcasting becomes the model global id
2. hash, the named broadcasting becomes a query parameter
3. string, the name broadcasting becomes the string itself

So stream_for works like this  `stream_for -> broadcasting_for -> stream_from`

[`broadcasting_for`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/914caca2d31bd753f47f9168f2a375921d9e91cc/actioncable/lib/action_cable/channel/broadcasting.rb#L24) is the mechanism that ActionCable uses to generate unique named broadcastings for objects in your application. This ensures every object has a unique identifier in your application lifecycle.

For ActiveRecord models, rails call `to_gid_param` on them which returns a unique identifier for that model instance. If you update the model, change an attribute, reload the model, calling `to_gid_param` on that model will always return the same string. You can try this in your rails console, call `to_gid_param` on an AR model instance.

For other types of objects, rails call `to_param` which converts the object to URL safe query parameters. One special case is Array, see [how rails handle that here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/914caca2d31bd753f47f9168f2a375921d9e91cc/actioncable/lib/action_cable/channel/broadcasting.rb#L30).

### [`stream_from`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/Channel/Streams.html#method-i-stream_from)

The fundamental difference here is that you don't need to pass a model, just pass a string as the named broadcasting and you are good to go. If you pass anything other than a string, [it still gets converted to a string](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/914caca2d31bd753f47f9168f2a375921d9e91cc/actioncable/lib/action_cable/channel/streams.rb#L77).

### Clarifying your doubts

> One interesting thing to point out is that using the stream_for approach, you can still use ActionCable.server.broadcast("chat:#{room}", data) (note the change of _ to :) but you cannot use ChatChannel.broadcast_to with the stream_from approach.

Well, `broadcast_to` still ends up calling `ActionCable.server.broadcast` if you want this sort of behavior in all of your channels, you can just add a `broadcast` class method to your base class typically `ApplicationCable::Channel`

```rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base
    def self.broadcast(broadcasting, data)
      ActionCable.server.broadcast(broadcasting, data)
    end
  end
end
```

You can even take it a step further by unifying broadcast_to here, since you have access to `braodcasting_for` in your channel. Try `ChatChannel.broadcasting_for(arg)` in your rails console passing different value including models to see what I mean.

> `stream_from` is more "dangerous" as it sets a global room that requires a convention maintained by the author(s). Additionally, broadcasting can only be done directly from ActionCable.server.

Like I said earlier you can circumvent this, see the easy solution above. As for `stream_for` being more dangerous how would you define dangerous? If you mean because you have to maintain the named broadcasting yourself, I will provide you with instances where this makes sense.

> In your example, you said `stream_from` sets a global room.

Note that a subscription will not be established, except your client code explicitly subscribe to your channel. So even if you use `stream_for "chat_#{params[:room]}"` a connection will never be established unless your client-side code subscribes to the room.

> If I had both a ChatChannel and NotificationChannel and both contain stream_from 'common', I'd be able to broadcast on both channels at once with ActionCable.server.broadcast('common', data). This seems like a code smell to me though.

The ActionCable docs recommend that at the very least, [a consumer should be subscribed to one channel](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#terminology-channels).
How you choose to use `stream_from` is what results in a code smell, this is not a problem with ActionCable/Rails.

### When should one use `stream_from`?

If you plan to craft complex named broadcasting to route messages to a client based on roles or some criteria, using `stream_from` can help you here. This will ensure only users that meet those defined criteria gets the broadcast.

Example

I want to broadcast a message to everyone in a room

```rb
 class ChatChannel <  ApplicationCable::Channel
    def subscribed
      room = Room.find_by_name params[:room]

      stream_for room 
    end
  end
```

The client will end up subscribing to this channel like this

```js
consumer.subscriptions.create({ channel: "ChatChannel", room: "gaming" })
```

Every client will get this message.

What if you want to enforce some sort of security without reaching for a complex solution? We can use `stream_from` to achieve some sort of privacy. Say you want to send a message to a particular user in the Gaming room, we can craft a named broadcasting like so

```rb
 class ChatChannel <  ApplicationCable::Channel
    def subscribed
      stream_from "chat_#{params[:room]}_#{params[:user]}"
    end
  end
```

The client will end up subscribing to the above channel like so

```js
consumer.subscriptions.create({ channel: "ChatChannel", room: "gaming", user: "1" })
```

This way if you broadcast a message to the above-named broadcasting, only the user with ID 1 will get the message.

Comment: Thanks for the incredible and thorough write up!  I've been playing with AC a bit more and come across some examples that use [`identified_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/Connection/Identification/ClassMethods.html#method-i-identified_by) as well. It seems like `stream_from` is the base method that is exposed (Rails' "sharp knives") if you'd like to manage channels and rooms yourself where as `stream_for` and other tools allow you to follow Rails conventions for objects and users.